# How to add short-key for "Add Definition in class.cpp" in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

When you define a member function in a class Interface in Qt creator you can right click on the function prototype and select **Refactor->Add Definition in YouClass.cpp** . But this will be really handy If you can set a shortcut for it. I couldn't find it in options->shortcut section.
[image]

For example in Visual Assist you can press ALT+SHIFT+Q.

Comment: There is no such option. See [this bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-3715).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> You can press Alt+Enter to open a context menu that contains refactoring actions, which are available at the current cursor position.

This is also mentioned in the documentation under [Refactoring C++ Code](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-editor-refactoring.html#applying-refactoring-actions)

Maybe a solution with a macro or something in that direction exists as well.

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by @Robin Karlsson:

> You can press Alt+Enter to open a context menu that contains refactoring actions available in the current cursor position.

As mentioned by @Dmitry Volosnykh, the above appears in the documentation (more concretely at [Applying Refactoring Actions](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-editor-refactoring.html#applying-refactoring-actions)
)