# How to redefine the way Qt Creator creates getter and setter functions?

Tags: c++, qt, refactoring, qt-creator, automated-refactoring

Is it possible to edit how QtCreator generates the signatures for "getter and setter" functions from the refactor context menu? Specifically, it gives me this right now when I define getter/setter for "m_camera":

```
std::shared_ptr<CameraGrabber> camera() const;
void setCamera(const std::shared_ptr<CameraGrabber>& camera);
private:
   std::shared_ptr<CameraGrabber> m_camera;
```

When in fact I want to get something like this instead:

```
auto camera() const -> std::shared_ptr<CameraGrabber> ;
void setCamera(std::shared_ptr<CameraGrabber> camera);
private:
   std::shared_ptr<CameraGrabber> m_camera;
```

This is with QtCreator version 4.0.3;  perhaps there is some custom plugin or template definition file that can be used to control how get/set functions are declared?

related:

[qtcreator customize getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162580/qtcreator-customize-getters-and-setters#)

[How to add short-key for "Add Definition in class.cpp" in Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853753/how-to-add-short-key-for-add-definition-in-class-cpp-in-qt-creator)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible at the moment, neither with qtcreator itself nor with any plugins that I'm aware of.

I suggest you vote for the corresponding feature request: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-12678 .

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be for you to make your own build of Qt Creator (this can be done from within Qt Creator!), and modify the plugin that does the refactoring to your taste. It should be a minimal change I think.